# Errors when trying to code button press to add strings to an array

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to get a touch up inside on a button to record the title of the button as a string in the resultsStack, but I'm getting these errors:

`var resultsStack` is giving me error:

> missing argument for parameter #1 in call

also, in my `if`/`else` I'm getting

> EmotionsQuestionsViewController does not have a member named resultsStack

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I've modeled it on the steps used to make the calculator in this course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLJtT7eSykg

```
class EmotionQuestionsViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var emotionQuestion: UILabel!

    var resultsStack = Array()
    var questionsStack = Array(arrayLiteral: "HAPPY", "JOYFUL", "SAD", "ANXIOUS")
    var i = [0]

    @IBAction func RecordValueFromNumericalScaleOneToSeven(sender: UIButton) {


        let value = sender.currentTitle!
        resultsStack.append(value)

        if resultsStack.count < questionsStack.count{
        //change lablel to next string in questionsStack array & increase i count by 1
        }
        else{
        //advance to resultsViewController
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error,

> EmotionsQuestionsViewController does not have a member named resultsStack

is caused purely because of the first error.  Eliminating the first error will eliminate this one.

---

The first error is happening because you need to specify the type of your array.  Something like this:

```
var resultsStack = Array<<#type#>>()
```

Where `<#type#>` is replaced with whatever type you need.  For example, it looks like you might want an array of `String`s?  So you might want to use:

```
var resultsStack = Array<String>()
```

which can also be written as:

```
var resultsStack = [String]()
```

or

```
var resultsStack: [String] = []
```

All three of these do the same thing.

Comment: You can also write the subsequent line as `var questionsStack = ["HAPPY", "JOYFUL", "SAD", "ANXIOUS"]` – the `arrayLiteral:` initializer isn’t really meant to be used directly.